# Simple XML file triggering CSP error over a non-existent image?

Tags: xml, express, content-security-policy, helmet.js

I have an Express server with the following [helmet-csp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/helmet-csp) (a middleware handling content security policies to prevent vulnerabilities like XSS and frame injection) configuration:

```
server.use(csp({
    directives: {
      defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
      scriptSrc: ["'self'", '*.google-analytics.com'],
      imgSrc: ["'self'", '*.google-analytics.com'],
      connectSrc: ["'none'"],
      styleSrc: ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", 'maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com'], // Remove unsafe-inline for better security
      fontSrc: ["'self'"],
      objectSrc: ["'self'"],
      mediaSrc: ["'self'"],
      frameSrc: ["'self'"]
    }
  }));
```

I also have in my root, a **browserconfig.xml** file with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<browserconfig>
    <msapplication>
        <tile>
            <square70x70logo src="/mstile-70x70.png"/>
            <square150x150logo src="/mstile-150x150.png"/>
            <square310x310logo src="/mstile-310x310.png"/>
            <wide310x150logo src="/mstile-310x150.png"/>
            <TileColor>#da532c</TileColor>
        </tile>
    </msapplication>
</browserconfig>
```

As you can see, it's a simple XML file with no image data, much less SVG. And yet, when I try hitting https://www.schandillia.com/browserconfig.xml, the following is thrown in the console:

> Refused to load the image 'data:image/svg+xml,http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23909090' width='10'
>   height='10'>' because it violates
>   the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self'
>   *.google-analytics.com".

Do note that the contents of the XML file are also being displayed in the browser screen. It's just the console error that's confusing me. Where's the image file my server is complaining about?

**P.S.**: Is there any way to *allow* just this particular SVG (whatever it is, assuming it's safe and not malicious, coming from a source as legit as www.w3.org) in my `imgSrc` directive? I tried modifying my `server.csp()` but it didn't work:

```
server.use(csp({
    directives: {
      defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
      scriptSrc: ["'self'", '*.google-analytics.com'],
      imgSrc: ["'self'", 'data:', '*.google-analytics.com'],
      connectSrc: ["'none'"],
      styleSrc: ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", 'maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com'], // Remove unsafe-inline for better security
      fontSrc: ["'self'"],
      objectSrc: ["'self'"],
      mediaSrc: ["'self'"],
      frameSrc: ["'self'"]
    }
  }));
```

What's this mystery object and how can one make it stop bothering the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Chrome. It’ll happen with any XML file you navigate to (open) in Chrome that has no stylesheet associated with it. In that case, Chrome (for its own internal purposes) loads a disclosure-triangle image from `data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23909090' width='10' height='10'><path d='M0 0 L8 0 L4 7 Z'/></svg>` — or tries to.

If you have no CSP policy in place, Chrome loads that `data:` URL image fine with no error. But if you *do* have a CSP policy and it doesn’t allow `data:` sources, then the browser will block loading it.

There is a way you can make your CSP allow that image, but that way’s no safer than specifying `'unsafe-inline'` in your policy. The way is to include `data:` as a source for the `img-src` directive. But that’ll have the effect of allowing images from any `data:` URL.

Note also: the particular `data:` URL cited in the question doesn’t come from www.w3.org. Any SVG image anywhere will have that `xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'` part. That’s just the SVG namespace identifier.  So it doesn't indicate it's being served from www.w3.org, and doesn't imply it's necessarily safe or secure.